# sending JSON using post but getting empty object instead of data

Tags: javascript

this is my code which is getting an JSON from post request
I have connected the database in other file and it is getting connected
when I send data from JSON empty object getting printedd

```
 const express=require('express');
    const app =new express()
    const User=require('../2-mongoose/3-user')
    require('../2-mongoose/1-basic');// have to add this ccompulsory


app.use(express.json())// will convert string into obj
app.post('/users',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);// to console.log data sent through json
    res.send("testing");
    // const user=new User(req.body);
    // user.save().then(()=>{
    //     res.send(user);
    // }).catch((error)=>{
    //     res.status(400).send(error);
    // })
})
app.listen(8000,()=>{
    console.log("server fired off");
})
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide the code from where you are making this post request.

Comment: localhost:8000/users

Comment: {
    "name":"mahir"
}

Comment: Are you using postman??

Comment: yes i am using postman

Comment: Maybe you didn't send the right content type?

Comment: but it was working before with same code and same json

Comment: I am using Thunder client it is working  but not in postman

Comment: try with `res.json` instead of res.send

Comment: Can you please explain what it prints when you are printing the response??

Answer (score 1):

If you are using postman make sure you send data this way And obviously select the post method.

[image]

Follow the steps and check, I hope you will get your result. If not please clarify your problem with more details (Like result of executed code)